# Insert a value in the middle of iterating value in template tag

Tags: python, django

I am using for loop in django template to iterate the list and my goal is to display a string every after 3 values.

this is my list

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

This is my code

```
{% for a in myList %}

{{a}}
{% if forloop.counter == 3%}
<div>String</div>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I want to have something like

```
1 2 3 string 4 5 6 string 7 8 9 string
```

Comment: You can use {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}

Answer (score 0):

You can do as advised Kapil Sachdev

```
{% for a in myList %}
    {{ a }}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
        <div>String</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or you can use [cycle tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)

```
{% for a in myList %}
    {{ a }}
    {% cycle '' '' '<div>String</div>' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The `cycle` tag will be removed in Django 1.10. I recommend against it if you plan on updating to a newer version of Django down the line.